# Is it possible to load all functions of a script before it runs?

Tags: function, powershell

I have a rather complex script, which follows the following steps;

-->**Login** (Ask user to enter admin details)
--->**Start** (Queries Ad for user creditals)

--->**Progress** (Creates a progress bar)

--->**Search** (Carries out the search for the data)
--->**Question1** -(Yes - Select-Folder No - Create)

--->**Select-Folder** (Asks the user to create a file path for the document to be stored)
  --->**Go** (Creates a csv from the results of the search)

--->**Question2** (CSV - Result XLSX - Excel) (Asks the user if they wish to create a Xlsx file from the Csv)

--->**Create** (Checks to see if file path exists C:\temp\Server_shares if not creates it)
  --->**Done** (creates csv at default location C:\temp\Server_shares)

--->**Question2** (Asks the user if they wish to create a Xlsx file from the Csv)

--->**Question2** -(CSV - Result XLSX - Excel) (Asks the user if they wish to create a Xlsx file from the Csv)

--->**Result** (User has chosen not to create a Xlsx notifys the user of the file path)
  --->**End** (Closes script)

--->**Excel**  (creates Xlsx from csv and stores it in either default or user defined location)
  --->**Delete** (Deletes all remaingin Csv's from file path)
   --->**End** (Closes script)

it seems that I keep get unhandelled exception errors everytime that I run the code.

I have found out that it runs then loads the functions, I need to run them all in memory so that when called each one will run without error.

I have tried creating varibles for each function, but this exactly the same as what I have already.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName     ("Microsoft.VisualBasic")

$Script:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$Script:Ma3 = "C:\Temp\Server_Shares\"

Function Get-Event{


Function Get-Login {

Clear-Host

#Write-Host "Please provide admin credentials (for example  DOMAIN\admin.user and your password)"



 $Global:Credential = Get-Credential

 }

 Function Get-Start{    

    #Get user credentials 

    $Cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Your Credentials (Domain\Username)" 

    if ($Cred -eq $Null) 

                        { 

                            Write-Host "Please enter your username in the form of Domain\UserName and try again" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow 

                            Rerun 

                            Break                           

                        } 



    #Parse provided user credentials 

    $DomainNetBIOS = $Cred.username.Split("{\}")[0] 

    $UserName = $Cred.username.Split("{\}")[1] 

    $Password = $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().password 



    Write-Host "`n" 

    Write-Host "Checking Credentials for $DomainNetBIOS\$UserName" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor White 

    Write-Host "***************************************" 



    If ($DomainNetBIOS -eq $Null -or $UserName -eq $Null)  

                        { 

                            Write-Host "Missing domain please type in the following format: Domain\Username" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow 

                            Rerun 

                            Break 

                        } 

    #    Checks if the domain in question is reachable, and get the domain FQDN. 

    Try 

    { 

        $DomainFQDN = (Get-ADDomain $DomainNetBIOS).DNSRoot 

    } 

    Catch 

    { 

        Write-Host "Error: Domain was not found: " $_.Exception.Message -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 

        Write-Host "Please make sure the domain NetBios name is correct, and is reachable from this computer" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 

        Rerun 

        Break 

    } 



    #Checks user credentials against the domain 

    $DomainObj = "LDAP://" + $DomainFQDN 

    $DomainBind = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($DomainObj,$UserName,$Password) 

    $DomainName = $DomainBind.distinguishedName 



    If ($DomainName -eq $Null) 

        { 

            Write-Host "Domain $DomainFQDN was found: True" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 



            $UserExist = Get-ADUser -Server $DomainFQDN -Properties LockedOut -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $UserName} 

            If ($UserExist -eq $Null)  

                        { 

                            Write-Host "Error: Username $Username does not exist in $DomainFQDN Domain." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 

                            Rerun 

                            Break 

                        } 

            Else  

                        {    

                            Write-Host "User exists in the domain: True" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 





                            If ($UserExist.Enabled -eq "True") 

                                    { 

                                        Write-Host "User Enabled: "$UserExist.Enabled -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 

                                    } 



                            Else 

                                    { 

                                        Write-Host "User Enabled: "$UserExist.Enabled -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor RED 

                                        Write-Host "Enable the user account in Active Directory, Then check again" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor RED 

                                        Rerun 

                                        Break 

                                    } 



                            If ($UserExist.LockedOut -eq "True") 

                                    { 

                                        Write-Host "User Locked: " $UserExist.LockedOut -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 

                                        Write-Host "Unlock the User Account in Active Directory, Then check again..." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor RED 

                                        Rerun 

                                        Break 

                                    } 

                            Else 

                                    { 

                                        Write-Host "User Locked: " $UserExist.LockedOut -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 

                                    } 

                        } 



            Write-Host "Authentication failed for $DomainNetBIOS\$UserName with the provided password." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 

            Write-Host "Please confirm the password, and try again..." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 

            Rerun 

            Break 

        } 



    Else 

        { 

        Write-Host "SUCCESS: The account $Username successfully authenticated against the domain: $DomainFQDN" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 

        } 

        Search

}

 Function Rerun { 

    $Title = "Enter another set of Credentials?" 

    $Message = "Do you want to try another set of credentials?" 

    $Yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", "Try Again?" 

    $No = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", "End Script." 

    $Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Yes, $No) 

    $Result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $Options, 0)  



    Switch ($Result) 

    { 

        0 {Get-Start} 

        1 {"End Script."} 

    } 

} 

Function Get-Progress{

Try{

{If (Test-Path $PC -ErrorAction Stop) {







Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms



## -- Create The Progress-Bar

$ObjForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$ObjForm.Text = "Progress-Bar of searched folders"

$ObjForm.Height = 100

$ObjForm.Width = 500

$ObjForm.BackColor = "White"



$ObjForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle

$ObjForm.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen



## -- Create The Label

$ObjLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

$ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "

$ObjLabel.Left = 5

$ObjLabel.Top = 10

$ObjLabel.Width = 500 - 20

$ObjLabel.Height = 15

$ObjLabel.Font = "Tahoma"

## -- Add the label to the Form

$ObjForm.Controls.Add($ObjLabel)



$PB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar

$PB.Name = "PowerShellProgressBar"

$PB.Value = 0

$PB.Style="Continuous"



$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size

$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500 - 40

$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20

$PB.Size = $System_Drawing_Size

$PB.Left = 5

$PB.Top = 40

$ObjForm.Controls.Add($PB)



## -- Show the Progress-Bar and Start The PowerShell Script

$ObjForm.Show() | Out-Null

$ObjForm.Focus() | Out-NUll

$ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "

$ObjForm.Refresh()



Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

    Out-Null

## -- Execute The PowerShell Code and Update the Status of the    Progress-Bar



$result = (get-acl $pc).Access  

$Counter = 0

ForEach ($Item In $Result) {

    ## -- Calculate The Percentage Completed

    $Counter++

    [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$Result.Count)*100

    $PB.Value = $Percentage

    $ObjLabel.Text = "Scanning $Folders For $criteria in $PC"

    #$ObjLabel.Text = "Found $counter Pst's in $Search"

    $ObjForm.Refresh()

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 150

    # -- $Item.Name

    #"`t" + $Item.Path







$ObjForm.Close()

#Write-Host "`n"





    Else {

#Write-Host

#Write-Host "`t Cannot Execute The Script." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

#Write-Host "`t $Search Does Not Exist in the System." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

#Write-Host

   }

   }

   }

   } 

   }

   Catch{

    Write-Host "Please enter a vaild path" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    Search

    }

     } 

    Function Script:Get-Question {

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

     $Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

     $Form1.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 100)

     $form1.topmost = $true

     $Text = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

     $Text.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, 15)

     $Text.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)

     $Text.Text = "Would you like to save the file to a custom location?"

     $Form1.Controls.Add($Text)

     #$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

     Function Button1

   {

   $Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

   $Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 55)

   $Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55, 20)

   $Button1.Text = "Yes"

   $Button1.add_Click({Get-Go -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   $Form1.Close()})

   $Form1.Controls.Add($Button1)

   }

     Function Button2

   {

   $Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

   $Button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(80, 55)

   $Button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55, 20)

   $Button2.Text = "No"

   $Button2.add_Click({Get-Create -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   $Form1.Close()})

   $Form1.Controls.Add($Button2)

  }

  Button1

 Button2

   [void]$form1.showdialog()

  }

  Function Select-FolderDialog{



     param([string]$Description="Select Folder",[string]    $RootFolder="Desktop")



 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName ("System.windows.forms")    | Out-Null     

 Write-host "Please minimize the console to select a folder in which to save the results"

 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog

 $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder

 $objForm.Description = $Description

 $objForm.ShowNewFolderButton = $false

 $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()

 If ($Show -eq "OK")

 {

     Return $objForm.SelectedPath

 }

 Else

 {

    Write-Error "Operation cancelled by user."

    Exit

 }

}

   Function Get-Search{

    Write-host "Please Minimize the console and enter the full folder path that you require permissions for" -ForegroundColor Green

   $Script:PC = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please enter the full path of the folder you wish to search", "Folder choice")



 If ($PC -eq "")

 {

 Exit

 }

Get-Progress

$Res = (get-acl $pc).Access  



 $Script:Gold = $Res| Select-object @{label = "User Groups";Expression =   {$_.IdentityReference}},
                        @{label = "Rights";Expression = {$_.FileSystemRights}},
                        @{label = "Access";Expression = {$_.AccessControlType}} 

Get-Question

}

Function Script:Get-Go{
$Form1.Close()
$FPath = Select-FolderDialog

$Folder = $FPath + "\" + [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox   ("Please select a folder to save the data to", "Path Choice") + "\"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

"Please minimize the console to select a folder in which to save the  results"

 $Name = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a filename", "File Name Choice")

 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null

 $cfgOutpath = $Folder + "$Name"

if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $Folder ) )

{

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Folder |out-null

 }

 Else{

[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('The directory already exists','Error','Ok','Error')

}

$Gold | Export-Csv "$cfgOutpath.csv" -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation



 Write-Host "File has been saved to $cfgOutpath.csv" -ForegroundColor Yellow
 Get-Q2
 }
  ##############################################
  ##          Testing Phases                  ##
  ##            Get-Start                     ##
  ##                                          ##
  ##############################################
  Search  

  Function Script:Get-Create {
  $Form1.Close()
  if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $Ma3 ) )

   {

  New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Ma3 |out-null

  }
  Done
  }

  Function Script:Get-Done{

  $PC2 = ($PC -split '\\')[-1]

  $CSV = "C:\Temp\Server_Shares\User access for $PC2"

  $cfgOutpath = $CSV

   $Gold | Export-Csv "$cfgOutpath.csv" -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation


   Get-Q2
  }

  Function Script:Get-Q2 {

 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

 $Form2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

 $Form2.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 100)

 $form2.topmost = $true

 $Text = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

 $Text.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, 15)

  $Text.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 40)

  $Text.Text = "Would you like to create an Xlsx document or leave it as csv?"

  $Form2.Controls.Add($Text)

  $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

 Function Button1

 {

 $Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

 $Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 55)

 $Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55, 20)

 $Button1.Text = "CSV"

 $Button1.add_Click({Get-Result

 $Form2.Close()})

 $Form2.Controls.Add($Button1)}


 Function Button2

 {

  $Button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

  $Button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(80, 55)

  $Button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55, 20)

  $Button2.Text = "XLSX"

  $Button2.add_Click({Get-Excel

  $Form2.Close()})

  $Form2.Controls.Add($Button2)

  }

  Button1

  Button2

 [void]$form2.showdialog()
 }


 Function Script:Get-Ans{
 $Form2.Close()
 Try{
    Get-Excel
  }
  Catch{
    Write-Host "Unable to create XSLX please check full path." -ForegroundColor Red
  }
  }

 Function Script:Get-Result{
  $Form2.Close()
 Write-Host "File has been saved to $CSV.csv" -ForegroundColor Yellow
 }

 Function Script:Get-Excel{
$RD = $Ma3 + "*.csv" 
$CsvDir = $RD 

$csvs = dir -path $CsvDir # Collects all the .csv's from the driectory 
$outputxls = "$Ma4.Xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.displayAlerts = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.add()
# Loops through each CVS, pulling all the data from each one
foreach($iCsv in $csvs){
    $iCsv
    $WN = ($iCsv -Split "\\")[5]
    $wn = ($WN -Split " ")[3]
    $WN = $WN -replace ".{5}$"
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
    $Excel.displayAlerts = $false
    $Worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.add()
    $Worksheet.name = $WN

    $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $iCsv)
    $Connector = $worksheet.Querytables.add($txtconnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
    $query = $Worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

    $query.TextfileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

    $Query.TextfileParseType =1
    $Query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.cells.column.count
    $query.AdjustColumnWidth =1

    $Query.Refresh()
    $Query.Delete()
    $Worksheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
    $Worksheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = $true
    $Worksheet.Rows.Item(1).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
    $Worksheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Underline = $true
    $Workbook.save()

    }
  $Empty = $workbook.worksheets.item("Sheet1")
   $Empty.Delete()
   $Workbook.SaveAs($outputxls,51)
  $Workbook.close()
   $Excel.quit()
   Write-Host "File has been saved to $outputxls" -ForegroundColor Yellow
   Delete
   }

   Function Script:Delete{
   get-childitem $MA3 -recurse -force -include *.txt | remove-item -force    #Removes all txt files from final directory
   get-childitem $MA3 -recurse -force -include *.csv | remove-item -force #Removes all CSV files from final directory
    }

   Write-Host "Finished"
   }

   Get-Event
  #Excel-Write'
```

I know it's a lot of code, but in-order for anyone to replicate the probelm, you will need it all.

I want it to run, first time, everytime, at the moment it take 3-4 tries before its loaded each function into memory.

Comment: All you need to do is put the functions at the top of the script. Powershell reads from Top of script to bottom.

Comment: As a sidenote: `LoadWithPartialName` has been deprecated. Use `Add-Type` instead for PowerShell 3.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your functions into a PowerShell module file.

```
C:\Module.psm1
```

And then import that module before anything else in the script:

```
Import-Module C:\Module.psm1
```

For larger scripts this makes things more manageable as you can keep your long list of functions separate from the script that calls them.

Comment: Great answers however some functions are contained in other functions, so like the dialog box to choose if you would like to create the xlsx or leave the csv. is there another way to approach this at all?

Comment: Functions can happily contain other functions inside a module, there should be no reason why you cant generate a prompt for XLSX creation using a nested function in a module.